# Alfresco PDF-Toolkit Javascript

Tags: pdf, alfresco, watermark, toolkit, alfresco-webscripts

i've recently installed Alfresco's [PDF-Toolkit](https://github.com/ntmcminn/alfresco-pdf-toolkit). My actual intension is to use it in a `Javascript` manner. This is because the value i need or want to watermark will be based on the Document's Property/Aspect.

i failed to find any tutorial or guide regarding this issue. if anyone can please give me a walkthrough, i'd really appreciate it.

my current script looks like this:

```
var watermark_action = actions.create("pdf-watermark");

watermark_action.parameters["destination-folder"] = ????;
watermark_action.parameters["watermark-type"] = "text";
watermark_action.parameters["watermark-text"] = aspect.ajie;
watermark_action.parameters["watermark-pages"] = "all";
watermark_action.parameters["watermark-depth"] = "over";
watermark_action.parameters["position"] = "center";

watermark_action.execute(document);
```

**NOTE:** i actually [found one](https://forums.alfresco.com/forum/developer-discussions/add-ons/location-watermark-pdf-toolkit-05232016-1543), the problem is that this one is an `image watermark` and what i want or need is a `text watermark`. also i need the script to save the watermarked copy to the **same directory** which i believe is not what the guide seems to do.

the last thing i need is the value for the `destination-folder` parameter. i really have no clue on how or what i'll place here just to save the pdf to the same folder. hoping to get some guide, tips, and tricks here. thanks

Comment: try to use "document.parent" if you run this script on particular document  then "document.parent"  will refer to folder under which it resides.

Comment: i tried this as `watermark_action.parameters["destination-folder"] = document.parent;` but i'm getting a `Could not run rules` error when i'm running the rule on a Folder Level :(

Comment: here is what my `Folder Rules` looks like -> http://i.imgur.com/RnNuJOK.png

Comment: What is the error in logs? You can also try with just "space". watermark_action.parameters["destination-folder"] ="space";

Comment: still having a `Cannot Run Rule` error. i've tried `watermark_action.parameters["destination-folder"] = document.parent` and `watermark_action.parameters["inplace"] = true` any ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code should look like this:

```
var watermark_action = actions.create("pdf-watermark");

watermark_action.parameters["inplace"] = true;
watermark_action.parameters["destination-folder"] = document.parent;
watermark_action.parameters["watermark-type"] = "text";
watermark_action.parameters["watermark-text"] = "Lorem Ipsum";
watermark_action.parameters["watermark-font"] = "Helvetica";
watermark_action.parameters["watermark-size"] = "14";
watermark_action.parameters["page"] = "all";
watermark_action.parameters["watermark-depth"] = "over";

watermark_action.parameters["position"] = "center";

watermark_action.execute(document);
```

You were missing watermark-font, watermark-size, and page.

Comment: this solved my problem. so the case is that, all parameters must be filled when i'm trying to execute pdf-toolkit via javascript ?. Thank you for such an effort Mr Potts (i am also the youtube guy who keeps asking you question. hehe) Case closed here. keeping this post to help future users too.